# How do I create a function that takes a numeric argument and prints “The argument is [argument]”

Tags: python, function, jupyter-notebook, arguments

This is the full question I am working on:
Create a function called Q6 that takes a numeric argument and prints “The argument is
[argument]” (for example: With argument 5, the function would print “The argument is 5”)

I got this question right but only because the grading system expected "5" to be the numerical argument. For future reference and proper understanding, I want to know what I would need to change in order for any numerical argument to be used. For example, if someone wanted the numerical argument to be "200", how would I change my function to allow this number to also be used? This is what I did below:

def Q6(x):
print('The argument is 5')

Comment: check out [f-strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/). `def Q6(x): return(f'The argument is {x}')`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using literal values as you did, you can use the parameter passed to the function and return it in an `f-string`:

```py
>>>def Q6(x): 
...    return f'The argument is {x}'
>>>
>>> Q6(200)
'The argument is 200'
>>> Q6(5)
'The argument is 5'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This makes sense but is there an alternative way to answer this question with a "print" instead of a "return"?

Comment: just replace the `return` with `print(f"The argument is {x}")`